# Load fragment in listview is lag

Tags: android

I have a problem with loading a fragment. My app has a listview in the menu slide. The List has 5 fragment. The only frag lagging when loading is the Home fragment. I tried to use `Hanle.destroy`, but it didn't fix it.
Im using Slide menu, Home Fragment verry lag when set content to it.
Link https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: what did you try by code ?!!

Comment: I'm using Slide menu, Home Fragment verry lag when set content to it. Link https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. Because Home Fragment contains a lot of elements with image and font type. I have arranged and collapsed them. It becomes smoother. But a little lag. That is inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. But what I can maybe suggest is, do you really need to use fragments in your listview?

Couldn't you rather complete what you need by using the viewHolder pattern with a  recycler view, by using a custom adapter to have custom views per entry in the recycler view?

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: thank! Ryno C. My english ability verry bad. :p.   I create a calendar. This app have menu sile with 5 item, item is fragment. I think Fragment Home load very data lead to lag. I try use asyncstask but not fixed. haizz, i really need use fragment because boss request. This App is fist my app and is app of fist my job.